# Proving that an operator is self-adjoint.

Tags: operator-theory, adjoint-operators

Let $(\lambda_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N^{*}}}$ be a sequence of real numbers converging to $0$ and let $(u_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N^{*}}}$ be an orthonormal family in a Hilbert space $H$. Define $T:H \rightarrow H$ by $$T(u) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \lambda_{k}\langle u,u_{k}\rangle u_{k}$$

Prove that $T$ is self-adjoint. could anyone help me please in doing so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

> $$T\text{ is self adjoint }\Leftrightarrow\langle Tx,x\rangle\in\mathbb{R}\text{ for every }x\in H.$$

Comment: And I will use also that $|<u,u_{k}>|^2$ is always real ..... right?

Comment: Yeap, that is always useful! In operator theory squares are always better than everything! ;)

Comment: Well, could you define the domain of the covariance operator, so as to be sure we're referring to the same object?

Comment: Could you also provide me with some link, since I do not own this book.

Comment: Yeap, if you're not allowing complex values, that's ok.

Comment: It's a real separable hilbert space

Answer (score 1):

Just use linearity and continuity of the inner product.

For any $x, y \in H$ we have:

\begin{align}
\langle Tx, y\rangle &= \left\langle \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda_k \langle x, u_k\rangle u_k, y\right\rangle \\
&=  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda_k \langle x, u_k\rangle \left\langle u_k, y\right\rangle \\
&= \left\langle x, \sum_{k=1}^\infty \overline{\lambda_k\langle u_k, y\rangle} u_k\right\rangle \\
&= \left\langle x, \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda_k \langle y, u_k\rangle u_k\right\rangle \\
&= \langle x, Ty\rangle 
\end{align}

Hence $T^* = T$.

Comment: where is Linearity and continuity of inner product  used? in which steps exactly ..... could u clarify please?

Comment: Is not linearity is used only if the sum is finite? but here we have infinite sum  so absolute convergence is used instead?

Comment: @Idonotknow Yes, linearity means that inner product commutes with finite linear combinations:
$$\left\langle \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k x_k, y\right\rangle = \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \langle x_k, y \rangle$$

Continuity means that inner product commutes with limits:
$$\left\langle \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n, y\right\rangle = \lim_{n\to\infty} \langle x_n, y\rangle$$

Comment: Putting this together, you can see that inner product commutes with infinite linear combinations too:

$$\left\langle \sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k x_k, y\right\rangle = \left\langle \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_k x_k, y\right\rangle = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left\langle \sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_k x_k, y\right\rangle = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \langle x_k, y \rangle = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k \langle x_k, y \rangle$$

Comment: From $\langle x, y\rangle = \overline{\langle y, x \rangle}$ we get that everything works in the second coordinate too, except the scalars are conjugated:

$$\left\langle x, \sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k y_k\right\rangle = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \overline{\alpha_k} \langle x, y_k \rangle$$